# Laravel - Eloquent to Json, and then sortBy on json object not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I have this json value that I want to be sorty but for some reason it's not working.

```
    [
        {
            "id": 15028,
            "order_id": 342,         
            "user_id": 3,
            "status": "1",
            "priority": "1",
            "donedate": null,
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Max"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 15030,
            "order_id": 341,         
            "user_id": 4,
            "status": "2",
            "priority": "1",
            "donedate": null,
            "user": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Jon"
            }
        }
    ]
```

This jSon structure is the result of Laravel eloquent object conversion using $object->toJson();

Now I keep this output in my Redis cache. What I want is to when the status and or priority of any order gets changed then I want to sort this jSon and store it back in Redis.

```
$order_list = collect($json_decoded_with_updated_values);
$order_list = $order_list->sortBy('status')->sortBy('priority');
Redis::set(\GuzzleHttp\json_encode($stich_list_in_collection));
Redis::set("orders_list", $orders_list, 302400);
```

However, I don't get a sort list. What I want to achieve is that, just like I would run two to three orderBy on an eloquent model like orderBy('status')->orderBy('priority')->get() .. I want to run the same two sortings on this json list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you are missing a `)` on the third line

Comment: What is the exact input that you are storing and the one that you are getting from redis.

Comment: you have json in redis and it returns that json and you are then trying to sort the json string?

Comment: @VinayakSarawagi This jSon I have mentioned, this is the exact thing stored in redis. I get this back from redis for a change and then want to sort it again both by either "status" or by "priority"

Comment: @lagbox yes that is correct. I just want to have this json sort if the status or priority key values get changed.

Comment: JSON is just a single "string" ... it is not those models, you have to convert it

Comment: @lagbox Can I somwhow change this JSON back to eloquent structure, do the required ->orderBy('status')->orderBy('priority') and then convert it back to json? Or is there any other way around it?

Comment: Rather than converting it to JSON, serialize it and unserialize it. Serialization works with all types of data types.

Comment: Well you're right but serializing an object and storing it in Redis would create a problem since it takes a lot more space. I have done the tests and json way takes at least 4 times less space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually we don't need to have a call-back as suggested by @brokedid. We can do it like following.

```
$order_list->sortBy('status')->sortBy('priority')->values()->all();
```

So I was missing the "->values()->all()" part. I hope if any one runs into the same problem in future, they can get a hint from this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by multiple Fields, then you could try to sort with a callback-method:

```
$orderedList = $unorderedList->sortBy(function($item) {
  return $item->priority.'-'.$item->status;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what's the result when you choose a different sort direction.

```
$order_list = $order_list->sortByDesc('status');
```